# how to count and echo the result to different columns

Tags: php, html, sql

how can i echo the result of COUNT to my three columns named: Resolved, Re-assigned and Closed?

i want to COUNT the number of Resolved, Re-assigned and Closed ticket and placed them to their corresponding column. I also need to sum up the Total of each column and row.

this is a ticketing system which has will be uploaded via Severity, Category 2, Category 3 and Status.

so in the image below, report will be generated with Unique values in each columns, so for Severity 5 we have two entries under Category 2 and would have different entries under Category 3 for each Category 2 then i want to show how many ticket were Resolved, Re-assigned and Closed for each entry under Category 3, for example SMP_Backend under Severity 5 has a Pending Request and others under Category 3, so for Pending Orders lets say we have Resolved 3 and Re-assigned 2. i want to show those numbers under Resolved and Re-assigned columns in Pending Request row and i also want to show its total per rows and per columns...

here is the image:

[image]

here is my code:

```
    <?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$dates = $_POST['dates'];

$sql ="SELECT trouble_type_priority as `Severity`
    , category_1
    , category_2
    , SUM(IF(status='Resolved', 1, NULL)) as `Resolved`
    , SUM(IF(status='Re-assigned', 1, NULL)) as `Re-assigned`
    , SUM(IF(status IN ('Closed','Suspended'), 1, NULL)) as `Closed`
    , COUNT(status) as `Total`
    FROM tbl_main
    WHERE resolved_date = '$dates'
    GROUP BY Severity, category_1, category_2";

$myData = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

$output = 
"<tr>
    <th colspan='3' align='center'>Ticket Bucket</th>
    <th colspan='3' align='center'>Status</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th width='auto' align='center'>Severity</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center'>Category 2</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center'>Category 3</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center'>Resolved</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center'>Re-assigned</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center'>Closed</th>
    <th width='auto' align='center'>Grand Total</th>
</tr>\n";
$prev1 = $prev2 = $prev3 = '';
while (list($trouble_type_priority,$category_1,$category_2) = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {

    if ($trouble_type_priority != $prev1) {
        $prCat1 = $trouble_type_priority;
        $prCat2 = $category_1;
        $prCat3 = $category_2;
        $prev1 = $trouble_type_priority; 
        $prev2 = $category_1;
        $prev3 = $category_2;
    }
    elseif ($category_1 != $prev2) {
        $prCat1 = '&nbsp';
        $prCat2 = $category_1;
        $prCat3 = $category_2;
        $prev2 = $category_1;
        $prev3 = $category_2;
    }
    elseif ($category_2 != $prev3) {
        $prCat1 = '&nbsp';
        $prCat2 = '&nbsp;';
        $prCat3 = $category_2;
        $prev3 = $category_2;
    }
    else $prCat1 = $prCat2 = $prCat3 = '&nbsp;';
    $output .= "<tr><td>$prCat1</td><td>$prCat2</td><td>$prCat3</td></tr>\n";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="PhpED Version 8.1 (Build 8115)">
<title>Example</title>
<meta name="author" content="Barand">
<meta name="creation-date" content="05/04/2013">
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" >
    <tr>
    <th>Team Report</th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="1" >
    <tr>
    <th colspan='2'>Remaining Tickets:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th width='72'>Wireless:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='WirelessRemaining' id='WirelessRemaining' size='5' align='middle' /></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Wireline:</th>
    <th><input type='text' name='WirelineRemaining' id='WirelineRemaining' size='5' align='middle' /></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="2">
        <?php echo $output?>
    </table>
    </table>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
    <td width="34" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="68" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="144" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="56" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="34" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="93" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="107" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="6" align="center">Total</td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: You're providing far too little information. What is the logic you need to determine whether a ticket is reassigned? And what is supposed to happen if a ticket is reassigned and resolved (and why not closed too) on the same day? Please edit your question to clarify, it's better to include too much information in your question than too little.

Comment: more info provided now...hope its clear already...

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is known as a *pivot* query.  Depending on your DBMS it can be accomplished with the `PIVOT` operator or a `CASE` statement.  Something like this:

```
select id, resolved, closed, resolved + closed as total
from (
    select   id
           , max(case type when 'R' then Q else 0 end) as resolved
           , max(case type when 'C' then Q else 0 end) as closed
    from (
       select id, type, count(type) as Q
       from cases 
       group by id, type
    ) as A
) as B
```